# How did Felice become a bird?

Tags: julian-may, saga-of-the-exiles

In Julian May's [Saga of Pliocene Exile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saga_of_Pliocene_Exile), at the very beginning of *The Nonborn King* Felice was described as a raven:

> Perched on a lone tree in the midst of the blooming savanna, the raven watched a pair of sabertooth cats cooperate in stalking their prey. ...  While the prey still struggled, the raven flew down, on fire with the old lust.  The cats withdrew before her coercive blast and crouched, snarling and hissing, as the predatory bird attacked one of the gazelle's great black eyes.  The beak struck like an ebon dagger.

also

> She plunged into the water and in a moment the raven was rocketing skyward, gripping a golden circlet in powerful talons.

It seems like she was actually transforming:

> The enormous bird glided down to stand near the head of the corpse.  The bereaved Tanu stared mutely at the bird, his green eyes dim with tears and his mouth a taut square of anguish.  Only when the raven's beak poised above the dead man's throat did the other cry out:
>   "Fian!"
>   She *did* know them, these rose-gold twins!  A paroxysm of anger dissolved the bird body, and a slender human woman wearing blue glass armor stood there.

How is she turning into a bird?  Is it an application of creative powers, or illusion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She uses her (extremely powerful) Paramount class creative metafunction.

In her case, unlike the firvulag, she can make a full transmutation, presumably storing her excess mass in the hyperspacial interstices but somehow retaining her full consciousness.

It appears only paramount creators can make a full transformation. Other examples being Marc's transformation of Hagen into a tarpon fish and Aiken Drum's various transformations into insects etc. Felice and Marc were explicitly named as paramount class, Aiken clearly demonstrated power in that range with his zap of Mount Mulhacen.

Mercy Rosmar might also qualify, for example, her innovative birthing technique.

Comment: I feel confident it is explicitly stated that Hagen isn't actually transformed, but the rest of this is good.

Comment: Felice was a large bird, so not much mass to lose. However Aitken was frequently smaller, much smaller but he also was not sure whether it was illusion, creativity-change or a mixture of both when he tried to explain to Raimo.